# Python pandas: groupby output duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

i have an excel data that i read in with python pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('..../file.txt', sep='\t')
```

Here i'm showing a mock data since my actual data is quite large:

```
data = {'ID': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,2],
    'VGene': ['IGHV1-J','IGHV1-J','IGHV2-J','IGHV2-J','IGHV1-J','IGHV1-J','IGHV2-J','IGHV2-J'],
    'JGene':['IGHJ4-1','IGHJ4-1','IGHJ5-1','IGHJ5-1', 'IGHJ4-1','IGHJ4-1','IGHJ5-1','IGHJ5-1'],
    'seq': ['AAAAAA','AAAAAC','TTTTTT','GGGGGG','AAAAAA','AAAAAC','TTTTTT','GGGGGG']}

data = DataFrame(data)

Out[13]: 
    ID  VGene    JGene     seq
0   0  IGHV1-J  IGHJ4-1  AAAAAA
1   1  IGHV1-J  IGHJ4-1  AAAAAC
2   2  IGHV2-J  IGHJ5-1  TTTTTT
3   3  IGHV2-J  IGHJ5-1  GGGGGG
4   4  IGHV1-J  IGHJ4-1  AAAAAA
5   5  IGHV1-J  IGHJ4-1  AAAAAC
6   6  IGHV2-J  IGHJ5-1  TTTTTT
7   2  IGHV2-J  IGHJ5-1  GGGGGG
```

for now i simply want to output the VGene, JGene, ID and seq for each VGene and JGene combination:

```
def printoutput(sgrp):
    return print(sgrp["ID"].unique(),sgrp["VGene"].unique(), sgrp['JGene'].unique(), sgrp['seq'].unique())

data.groupby(["VGene", "JGene"]).apply(printoutput)
```

the output:

```
 [0 1 4 5] ['IGHV1-J'] ['IGHJ4-1'] ['AAAAAA' 'AAAAAC']
 [0 1 4 5] ['IGHV1-J'] ['IGHJ4-1'] ['AAAAAA' 'AAAAAC']
 [2 3 6] ['IGHV2-J'] ['IGHJ5-1'] ['TTTTTT' 'GGGGGG']
```

seems right except that it prints out the first combination twice:

```
[0 1 4 5] ['IGHV1-J'] ['IGHJ4-1'] ['AAAAAA' 'AAAAAC']
[0 1 4 5] ['IGHV1-J'] ['IGHJ4-1'] ['AAAAAA' 'AAAAAC']
```

i tried it with a larger dataset and the same thing happened, the first instance always gets printed out twice. any idea on why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation for `groupby.apply` explains:

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first group to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first group.

I'd just use an old-fashioned loop and get on with my day:

```
>>> for k,g in df.groupby(["VGene", "JGene"]):
...     printoutput(g)
...     
[0 1 4 5] ['IGHV1-J'] ['IGHJ4-1'] ['AAAAAA' 'AAAAAC']
[2 3 6] ['IGHV2-J'] ['IGHJ5-1'] ['TTTTTT' 'GGGGGG']
```

(Note that there's no need for your `printoutput` function to return anything; right now, since `print` returns None, it's returning the same thing it would have if there were no `return` at all.)

Comment: thank you, but if my data set actually has more columns than i'm showing here, and i  want to print out only selected columns , how would i do that?

Comment: @Jessica: I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm calling *your* `printoutput` function, which only prints out the unique values for the columns *you* specified.  You can modify your function to print out as many or as few as you like.

Comment: say i only want to print out column 'VGene',  'JGene' and 'seq'? if i understand this correctly, k is pointing to the names of the columns and g is pointing to all of the columns?

Comment: @Jessica: you can add `print(k)` and `print(g)` to see.  `k` are the group keys (the values of VGene and JGene).  `g` are the rows associated with that key.  (Since you're grouping on VGene and JGene, those are always going to be boring columns to show, because they'll always only have one element.)